# What type to assign to children when they are all react components

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I need to access children's props in react using typescript. However, when I try to do it, I receive the following error:

```
Property 'props' does not exist on type 'string | number | boolean | {} | ReactElement<any, string | ((props: any) => ReactElement<any, string | ... | (new (props: any) => Component<any, any, any>)> | null) | (new (props: any) => Component<...>)> | ReactNodeArray | ReactPortal'.
  Property 'props' does not exist on type 'string'.
```

My Props

```
type MyProps = {
  title: string,
  children: React.ReactNode[],
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`React.Node` should be used when we don't know if children are a simple string, a number, a React element, etc.
When we want to have only React Component as possible children we have to use `React.ReactElement` instead. Furthermore, with react element, we can also specify the type of our children props by doing `React.ReactElement<MyProps>` or `React.ReactElement<MyProps>[]` in the specif case of an array.

So modify your props in:

```
type MyProps = {
  title: string,
  children: React.ReactElement<ChildrenProps>[],
}
```